# Computing the probability of reaching any leaf of an $n$-ary infinite probability tree

Tags: pr.probability, trees

Suppose you have two players $X$ and $Y$ fighting, both of which have $n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq1$ life.

Each player has a probability $p_i$ of doing $i$ damage for all $i\in[0, n]$. Note that $p_0$ is the probability of doing no damage, and all $p_i$ should sum to 1. $X$ and $Y$ both share probabilities, so all $p_i$ for $X$ equals $p_i$ for $Y$.

Now play the game as follows (each step is one turn):

1. Player $X$ attacks, and randomly deals $i$ damage to player $Y$ according to the distribution $p_i$. This means that $Y$ decreases their life by $i$.
2. Player $Y$ attacks, and randomly deals $i$ damage to player $X$ according to the distribution $p_i$. This means that $X$ decreases their life by $i$.

The game ends when a player's life is $\leq 0$.

Now a person watching this game would like for it to end after about $t\in \mathbb{N}, t\geq 1$ turns. In what ways can they assign the probabilities $p_i$ such that the expected number of turns is $t$?

Edit: To be clear I am looking for all possible $p_i$ such that the expected number of turns is $t$.

Comment: Set $p_{n/t}=1$?  I guess you want to rule that out...

Comment: Another simple example is $p_n=1/t$ and $p_0=1-1/t$ (if by "turn" you mean a single attack - if "turn" means a pair of attacks one by each player, then you can adjust appropriately).

Comment: So I'm looking for a description of the set of all possible $p_i$'s, not just one example.

Comment: You're asking for the expected damage each turn to be $n/t$. This condition is $\sum_{i=0}^n i\cdot p_i = n/t$. That exactly characterizes distributions you want.

Comment: @usul No, that's not the exact condition, even in the case of one player.  For example, if there's just one $i$ with $p_i = 1$, all the rest $0$, the lifetime is not $n/i$ but $\lceil n/i \rceil$.  The fact that there are two players also complicates matters.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, good point, depends how precise you want to be. ("end after about $t$") The two-player condition is interesting and I missed that it changes the distribution you want.

Comment: How is this unclear what I am asking? It is presented formally and has a precise answer.

Comment: Are both occurrences of $\mathbb R$ in the question typos for $\mathbb N$? It doesn't seem to make good sense with reals, and the accepted answer also seems to consider only integers.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Sorry, yes, I meant that the life and the expected number of turns should be in $\mathbb{N}$. Was that the confusion?

Comment: That being said, I think it's still a valid question if the life was in $\mathbb{R}$ as well, but that would then need continuous probabilities which I didn't specify was needed here so that is a different question, and I can see why that would be unclear. It does seem that having the expected number of turns could be in  $\mathbb{R}_+$ though, since expecting about 1.5 turns seems like a reasonable thing that someone might want to have occur (say, they want a about an equal chance of having 1 or 2 turns). But either way, yes, $\mathbb{N}$ is what I meant and that was a typo, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A(x,y)$ be the expected length of the game (counting each player's turn as $1$) if you start with the players having life points $x$ and $y$ respectively, the player with $x$ going next. 
Conditioning on the result of the first player's turn,

$$A(x,y) = 1 + \sum_{i < y} p_i A(y-i, x)$$

You're interested in $A(n,n)$, which this recursion will determine as a rather complicated rational function in the $p_i$.  For example, I get

$$ A({2,2})={\frac {{p_{{0}}}^{3}-{p_{{0}}}^{2}p_{{1}}-{p_{{0}}}^{2}+{p
_{{1}}}^{2}-p_{{0}}+p_{{1}}+1}{ \left( p_{{0}}+1 \right)  \left(1 -  p_{{0
}} \right) ^{3}}}
$$
while $A(3,3)$ is of the form $P(p_0, p_1, p_2)/((1+p_0)^3 (1-p_0)^5)$
where $P$ is a polynomial in $p_0, p_1, p_2$ of total degree $7$ with $39$ terms.  The condition $A(n,n) = t$ then determines a surface in $(p_0, \ldots, p_{n-1})$ space.

EDIT:
For example, here are the curves $A(2,2) = t$ in $(p_0,p_1)$ space for $t = 2$ to $10$ (from left to right).  Note that in this case any damage $\ge 2$ is immediately lethal, and 
$\sum_{i \ge 2} p_i = 1 - p_0 - p_1$.  For $A(2,2) = 1$ you'd need $p_0 = p_1 = 0$.

[image]

Comment: So recursive probability is really cool, I didn't know you could do that. And yes, I was manually playing with A(2, 2) and the solutions weren't pretty and I was confused. This fully describes all of them though, thanks =)

Comment: However to be fair, this does have one flaw. My question didn't assume that a player can only deal lethal damage, they might do more than lethal damage, since the condition is simply that life is $\leq 0$.

Comment: That's taken into account.  The sum is over $i < y$ precisely because any $i \ge y$ ends the game.

Comment: Also it's fun because this can easily be expanded to any number of players to get a very unhealthy function.